linux command to replace linefeed happened in the middle of the string
Current file:
COl1,COl2,COl3,COl4,COL5
AAA1,AAA1,AAA1,AAA1,AAA1
BBB10,BB11
,BB22,BB33
BB44
CCCC,CCC1,CCC2,CCC3
,CCC4,CCC5

Expected:
COl1,COl2,COl3,COl4,COL5
AAA1,AAA1,AAA1,AAA1,AAA1
BBB10,BB11,BB22,BB33,BB44
CCCC,CCC1,CCC2,CCC3

Looking for something to

check line feed and next line starting with comma then remove the linefeed
check line feed and next line starting/not starting with a pattern then remove the next line feed.

preferrably with sed.
The source is having unwanted linefeed in between strings and do not have double quotes for the boundary of string.
Tried the below, but it didn't work:
sed -z -i 's/\n,*/.../g'  filename


sed -z 's/\n,/,/g' should work, provided your sed supports the nonstandard -zoption. Demo: https://ideone.com/Tu5MbW

What is the logic for BB44 to be on the previous line? And where did ,CCC4,CCC5 go? And "The source is having unwanted linefeed in between strings and do not have double quotes for the boundary of string." But there is no example with double quotes.

There are no double quotes. It's just unwanted linefeeds. So looking for ways to clean thelinefeeds only if  it's an inbetween linefeed. not the reguler linefeed.

With the previous command ,CCC4,CCC5 is comming fine. Need a logic for BBB4. I am getting a ...(three dots in the begining. for BBB4. Can we use that as a pattern and remove the line feed. I tried the above command and it's not working.

Your question is extremely unclear. What does ,CCC4,CCC5 is comming fine mean? What does I am getting a ...(three dots in the begining. for BBB4 mean? Why did you think s/\n,*/.../g might work? You seem to have CSV but CSV doesn't have different numbers of fields per line so what is it? It's impossible to create a robust solution given what you've told us so far and only a very lucky guess could come up with a solution that does something you would accept. Please [edit] your question to provide clearer requirements and a better example demonstrating those requirements.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n,/,/;ta;s/\n([^,]+)$/,\1/;ta;P;D' file 

Turn on extended regexps -E.
Create a loop placeholder :a
Append the next line N (newline will be prepended to the next line).
Substitute a newline followed by a comma with a comma.
If the last substitution was successful, jump back to the loop placeholder.
If the last substitution was unsuccessful, substitute a newline followed by a string on non-commas with a comma followed by the that string.
If the last substitution was successful, jump back to the loop placeholder.
In all cases, print the first line in the pattern space and then delete the first line in the pattern space.
N.B. After a D command if the pattern space is not empty no next line is implicitly placed in the pattern space and the sed cycle begins again.

Using GNU sed
$ sed -E ':a;N;s/(([A-Z]+)[^\n]+)\n,*(\2)/\1,\3/;ba' input_file
COl1,COl2,COl3,COl4,COL5
AAA1,AAA1,AAA1,AAA1,AAA1
BBB10,BB11,BB22,BB33,BB44
CCCC,CCC1,CCC2,CCC3,CCC4,CCC5


Thanks everyone. the last sed worked in my case.

The question is poorly constrained, but here's a perl solution that uses stream processing, like sed or awk.  Probably it could be expressed similarly in awk.
 perl -n -e 'chomp;s/^,//;@F=split/,/;print ($F[0]!~/^$last/?"\n":",") if $last; print join ",",@F;($last=$F[$#F])=~s/\d+//;print "\n" if eof;' infile > outfile


perl -n process input stream where each line is $_ for processing
chomp - remove the line break from $_
s/^,// - remove the leading comma from $_
@F=split/,/ - split the remaining $_ into an array using comma as delimiter.  (Similar to perl -aF, but need to remove leading comma first)
print ($F[0]!~/^$last/?"\n":",") if $last - if the start of the 1st field doesn't match the start of the prior line's last field, print a line break, otherwise print comma.  All provided the last line's last field is nonempty
print join ",",@F - print the fields joined by a comma (no linebreak)
($last=$F[$#F])=~s/\d+// - remove digits and save prefix of last field as $last
print "\n" if eof add a linebreak for end-of-file

